# Why does assigning a function into another variable does something

Tags: python

I came from c++ and i'm confused why does calling outsideFunc(printer) doesn't do anything but if assigned it into another object it does something?

```
def outsideFunc(func):

    def insideFunc():
        print("Executing Inside Function")
        print(func())
        print("End Inside Function")
    
    return insideFunc 

def printer():
    return "Hello World"

outsideFunc(printer) #why doesnt this do the functionality of insideFunc

#but this one below does
display = outsideFunc(printer)
display()
```

Comment: because what you are doing in your assignment is basically writing `outsideFunc(printer)()`. Basically `outsideFunc` returns a function, so you need to call it again to make the inside function run

Comment: Why should `outsideFunc(printer)` execute `insideFunc`? There's nothing in your code that would call it.

Comment: @oskros it returns insideFunc() which does print

Comment: @iZner no, it returns `insideFunc`, it doesn't return `insideFunc()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
def outsideFunc(func):
    def insideFunc():
        print("Executing Inside Function")
        print(func())
        print("End Inside Function")
    return insideFunc
```

What this outside function does is *create* a function (the inside one, that calls what you passed to the outside function) and then returns that function to the caller. It in no way actually *calls* the inside function.

Functions in Python are first class objects that can be passed around and bound to other names, just like any other object.

The two ways you call this outer function are described below:

```py
# This passes `printer` to the outside function and it returns a function
# that will call it. It proceeds to throw away that function since you don't
# actually bind it to anything.

outsideFunc(printer)

# The first line below does exactly the same as the line above but it
# binds the function to the display name.
# The second line then uses that name to CALL the function, running
# the code within it.

display = outsideFunc(printer)
display()
```

The function/result-of-function difference is similar to the following:

```py
def fortyTwo():
    return 42

print(fortyTwo)
print(fortyTwo())

twiceTwentyOne = fortyTwo
print(twiceTwentyOne)
print(twiceTwentyOne())
```

The first `print` will simply print out the representation of the function itself, something like `<function fortyTwo at 0x7f9822dcb4c0>`. The second will actually *call* that function and print out what it returns. The way it knows to call it is the presence of the `()` following the name.

The final three lines show the function being bound to another name, which you can also call to get the same effect.

---

As an aside, if you wanted your two code segments to be identical in function, you would need to call the function returned in the first case, with something like:

```py
outsideFunc(printer)()
```

Comment: "Functions in Python are first class objects that can be passed around, just like variables." just like *any other object*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: thanks for that, it's a much better way to put it so I've updated the answer to include it.

Answer (score 2):

You return `return insideFunc` which is a function, think C++ lambda, which you can then call later.